# Items are not adding or updating to the ListView

Tags: android, azure, listview

My current issue is that the items that I have stored in my database are not loading into a listview. I am using android studio with java, I am also using an Azure Database with SQL statements as my querying methods. Azure is not able to use specific commands to withdrawl information.

```
/**
     * Refresh the inventory list with the items in the Table
     */
    private void refreshItemsToInventoryList() {

        // Get the items that weren't marked as completed and add them in the
        // adapter

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {
                    final List<Item> results = refreshItemsFromInventoryTable();

                    //Offline Sync
                    //final List<ToDoItem> results = refreshItemsFromMobileServiceTableSyncTable();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mInventoryAdapter.clear();

                            for (Item item : results) {
                                mInventoryAdapter.add(item);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (final Exception e){
                    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                }

                return null;
            }
        };

        runAsyncTask(task);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh the list with the items in the Inventory Table
     */

    @Nullable
    private List<Item> refreshItemsFromInventoryTable() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        ResultSet rs;
        List<Item> inventoryItems = null;
        try {
            con = connectionclass(username, password);
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Inventory; ";
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()) {
                inventoryItems.add(new Item(rs.getString("ItemDescription")));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException sql)
        {
            createAndShowDialog(sql.getMessage(), "Error");
        }

        return inventoryItems;
                //.where()
                //.execute()
               // .get();
    }
```

Can anyone figure out why my items are not loading to my list and why they are not appearing into the listview? Keep in mind that I am using Android Studio.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you with such little detail about what's wrong and the error you are seeing. Way too vague

Comment: are you able to get the data? is it just ui not updating or you are not getting the data as well?

Comment: whats in refreshItemsFromInventoryTable()

Comment: debug your code. you probably arent adding in ur item correctly

Comment: @DroiDev as it turns out, i am not getting any information into my inventoryItems table. is there a solution to this?

Comment: is there a solution to add items to a List? yeah.... add them. lol

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter once you are done with adding new data otherwise your listview won't reflect new changes

```
for (Item item : results) {
    mInventoryAdapter.add(item);
}
mInventoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference

Comment: @DarrenLeh it means there's an exception in try block and null list is returned